# how to get media:thumbnail from RSS feed via Scrapy CSS selector

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I am trying to read an RSS feed containing image url. XML file is something like below.

```
<item>
<title>Item Title Goes Here</title>
<link>https://www.google.com</link>
<media:thumbnail url="https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/03aizylUVApdyLAIku1AvRV-39.fit_scale.size_1028x578.v1605559903.png" height="251" width="330"/>
<media:content url="https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/03aizylUVApdyLAIku1AvRV-39.fit_scale.size_1028x578.v1605559903.png" type="image/png" height="600" width="800"/>
</item>
```

Getting data from tags title and others are fine:

```
title.css('title ::text').get()
```

However i am not able get data for <media:thumbnail url> via CSS selector. Any thought ?

Comment: can someone help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The url from thumbnail will be get:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('RSS.xml', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features='xml')

# Read the attribute url
print(soup.find('thumbnail').attrs['url'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Hermann12 for quick response. BTW, i figure out lately how to do it with Scrapy. This worked for me: title.css(' ::attr(url)').get()

Comment: I still see issue with scrapy to get data for other such tags. Here is a tag from RSS feed which i would like to get data using css selector with scrapy -  <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[ <p>ONCE upon a time there were four little Rabbits, and their names were—<strong>Flopsy, Mopsy, Cotton-tail, and Peter</strong><br /> They lived with their Mother in a sand-bank, underneath the root of a very big fir tree</p>]]>
    </content:encoded>